# To prove that a set is a subspace

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, bivariate

[image]

I am having trouble showing that the criteria for a set to be a subspace is true for this particular set.

Using the condition given here , I can obtain correlation in terms of $b$ and $a$ but I am  not able to use it prove that $c(a,b) + d(u,v)$ belongs to $S$, where $(a,b)$ and $(u,v)$ belong to $S$, $c$ and $d$ belong to $R$.

Comment: Can you translate the condition "$aX+bY$ is independent of $Y$" into a numerical condition on $(a,b)$?  It will need to be expressed in terms of the correlation between $X$ and $Y,$ but you know that such a correlation exists and that will suffice to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes i know that condition. It is rho= -b/a or rho=-v/u. But i still can't prove it using this condition.

Comment: So the fixed (though unknown) quantity $\rho$ must equal $-\frac ba$ which suggests to me that the points $(a,b)$ for which $aX+bY$ is independent to $Y$ must be of the form $\left(a, -\rho a\right)$. Sure looks like a straight line through the origin in the $a$-$b$ plane and so a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Understood.I totally went over this fact.Thanks!